# Trigger parent function on ajax success in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I know how to get a parent function to run if you trigger it on a onClick event (or similar), but I want to trigger it on ajax success. So pretty much this constallation:

```
var parent = React.createClass({
    someFunction: function(){
        console.log("Parent function triggered");
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <Child callback={this.someFunction} />
        );
    }
});

var child = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { data: "Wat" };
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "some_url",
            method: 'POST',
            data: this.state.data,
            success: function(response){
                this.props.callback; // This is what I would like to do
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Couldn't do it cap'n");
            }
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>Hello!</div>
        );  
    }
});
```

I could do it by triggering an event, but surely it should be possible to do it when I have access to the function. The function is also passed down correctly, and I can see it as a function if I do a `console.log(this.props.callback);`

Comment: What you have done is pretty much correct. You just need to execute that function in this way - this.props.callback(). Change the function's this keyword, or simply declare var that = this, and call that.props.callback()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to change the function's `this` keyword:

```
success: function(response){
  this.props.callback(); // This will work
}.bind(this),
```

Originally, the `this` keyword inside the anonymous function you're passing as the `success` option to the `ajax` method is not the same `this` it's outside it.

That happens because of Javascript's lexical scope, and you can change this behavior by overriding what the `this` keyword will be when the function is called.

---

Another option is to use a helper variable, e.g:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    /* (...) */
    success: function(response) {
      self.props.callback(); // this will work as well
    },
    /* (...) */
  });
}
```

---

One more option would be [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b)'s suggestion, to use the jQuery's AJAX `context` option:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $.ajax({
    /* (...) */
    context: this,
    success: function(response) {
      this.props.callback(); // this will work as well
    },
    /* (...) */
  });
}
```

---

And a last option, since you're using React, you're probably transpiling your code through Babel, so, you can take advantage of the [ES6's arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), that will automatically lexically the `this` binding:

```
success: (response) => {
  this.props.callback(); // This will work too
},
```

Comment: !! You need to do `self.props.callback()` (with parentheses), otherwise the callback will not execute.

Comment: Just use arrow functions: `success: () => this.props.callback()`.

Comment: @KevinB updated my answer to include your suggestion

Comment: @FelixKling arrow functions are not widely supported yet.

Comment: @wintvelt that's not exactly his question

Comment: @Buzinas: This question is about React. We can assume the OP uses Babel for transpiling JSX, which in turn has support for arrow functions.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, you're right

Comment: @Buzinas, to quote from OP question: "how to get a parent function to *run*". To run, you need parentheses. (may be simple typo, but still..)

Comment: @wintvelt ok, you have convinced me :)

Comment: @FelixKling added that option in the answer too :)